# Проблема с выводом массива на Masm`e

Tags: masm32

Массив от 0 до 20. А выводит что-то не понятное, и не могу никак отсделить где ошибка.Помогите пожалуйста.

```
.data
array WORD 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20

.code
Main:
invoke GetStdHandle, hStdout
mov hStdout, eax
invoke GetStdHandle, hStdin
mov hStdin, eax
xor ecx, ecx
xor eax, eax
lea esi, array
print:
mov dx, [esi]
call deb
xor edx, edx
inc ecx
inc esi
cmp cx, arraySize
jl print
deb proc
push ecx
invoke wsprintfA, offset lpOut, offset formatString, dx
invoke WriteConsoleA, hStdout, offset lpOut, sizeof lpOut, 0, 0
invoke  WriteConsoleA, hStdout, offset newLine, sizeof newLine, 0,0
pop ecx
ret
deb endp

invoke Sleep, 12000d
invoke ExitProcess, 0
end Main
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Так как массив word, то индексация должна быть не [esi], a [esi + ecx*2]